# Postfix: What does orig_to mean when using virtual_alias_domains?

Tags: postfix

I'm running a postfix server with the primary domain being domainA.com (configured in mydestination)

There is a second domain, domainB.com configured under virtual_alias_domains

I have user accounts for domainB.com mapped using virtual_alias_maps like this:

```
user@domainB.com          user
```

Now, when I receive mail for an account user@domainB.com I'm seeing log entries in maillog like:

```
Jun 23 17:51:39 mailhost postfix/pipe[8892]: 415BD41671: **to=<user@domainA.com>, orig_to=<user@domainB.com>**, relay=spamassassin, delay=1.5, delays=0.74/0.01/0/0.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
```

My question is: 
Is this normal behaviour? Why the translation in domain?

Comment: Yes that expected behavior. What do you mean by **translation in domain**?

Comment: Well it appears that postfix is rewriting the domain from domainB.com to domainA.com, I just wanted a little more understanding of what postfix is doing.

Comment: Check my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The short answer*: **YES**. Maillog entry indicated normal behavior of postfix.

*Explanation:*

In your `virtual_alias_maps` table you put

```
user@domainB.com          user
```

Here postfix rewriting engine works

1. You send email to user@domainB.com
2. Because postfix find `user@domainB.com          user` in your virtual_alias_maps table, postfix will rewrite email destination **user@domainB.com -> user**
3. In the right entry, you don't put any domain (e.g. you just put **user**). By default postfix will append this email address became user@`$myorigin`. This behavior controlled by [append_at_myorigin](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_at_myorigin) parameter. Variable `$myorigin` controlled by [myorigin](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myorigin) parameter.
4. In your case, looks like **append_at_myorigin** is set to **yes** and **myorigin** is set to **domainA.com**